# If statement error / not applying if statement

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, xts, zoo

I am attempting to produce a piece of code that is similar to functions such as `rollapply` from zoo/xts but applicable to my needs. I produced the code using some very simple sample data and everything has worked fine. But now that I attempt to run it on the `edhec` data I am receiving an error. I am unclear why but assume it is something to do with the if statement. Is anyone able to diagnose why I am receiving the error?

```
#rm(list=ls()) #Clear environment
cat("\014") #CTRL + L

library(xts)
library(lubridate)

is.even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0 

roundUp <- function(x,to=2)
{
  to*(x%/%to + as.logical(x%%to))
}

functionTest <- function(data, window, slide){

  nyears_t = nyears(data)

  #IF statement for non-even numbers only
  if(is.even(nyears_t == FALSE)) {
    nyears_t <- roundUp(nyears_t)
    data_extend <- data

    start_extend <- .indexyear(data)[length(data)]+ 1900 + 1
    end_extend <- start_extend + length(data) - 1
    index(data_extend) <- update(index(data),year=start_extend:end_extend)

    data <- rbind(data, data_extend)

    warning("WARNING! The function has looped to the start of the timeseries. The final list(s) 
            will contain years that do not exist in the dataset. Please modify.")
  }

  nslides = nyears_t/slide

  #Matrix
  year_1 = (.indexyear(data)[1]+1900)

  start <- seq(from = year_1, by = slide, length.out = nslides)
  end <- start + window - 1 

  mat <- matrix(c(start, end), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c(1:nslides), c("start", "end")))

  #For loop
  subsetlist <- vector('list')

  for(i in 1:nslides){
    subset <- data[paste0(mat[i,1], "/", mat[i,2])]
    subsetlist[[i]] <- subset
  }
  print(subsetlist)
}
```

Sample code that was used when I was making the function above:

```
a <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2000", format = "%Y"), to = as.POSIXct("2008", format = "%Y"), by = "year")
a <- as.xts(1:length(a), order.by = a)
a

functionTest(data = a, window = 3, slide = 2)
```

Sample code I am testing on and receiving an error:

```
> data(edhec, package = "PerformanceAnalytics")
> edhec <- edhec[,1:3]
> edhec <- edhec["/2007"]
> head(edhec)
           Convertible Arbitrage CTA Global Distressed Securities
1997-01-31                0.0119     0.0393                0.0178
1997-02-28                0.0123     0.0298                0.0122
1997-03-31                0.0078    -0.0021               -0.0012
1997-04-30                0.0086    -0.0170                0.0030
1997-05-31                0.0156    -0.0015                0.0233
1997-06-30                0.0212     0.0085                0.0217
> functionTest(data = edhec, window = 3, slide = 2)
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in start_extend:end_extend : NA/NaN argument 
>
```

**UPDATE:**

The code now runs with the following updates to the if statement (with thanks to Joshua Ulrich) (see code below). However, there is still a problem with the if statement - it appears to run regardless of whether there are an even or odd number of years present in the dataset. Although this does not impact the accuracy of the function, it may become problematic as large datasets are considered. If anyone has any thoughts on this it would be much appreciated. Otherwise this has been super already! Cheers

```
if(is.even(nyears_t == FALSE)) {
    nyears_t <- roundUp(nyears_t)
    data_extend <- data

    start_extend <- .indexyear(data)[nrow(data)] + 1900 + 1
    end_extend <- start_extend + nyears(data) - 1

    dates <- index(data)
    tmp <- as.POSIXlt(dates)
    tmp$year <- tmp$year + nyears(data)
    dates2 <- as.POSIXct(tmp, tz = tz)
    index(data_extend) <- dates2

    data <- rbind(data, data_extend)

    warning("WARNING! The function has looped to the start of the timeseries. The final list(s) 
            will contain years that do not exist in the dataset. Please modify.")
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `length` on a matrix (which is what the `coredata` of xts/zoo objects is) gives you the total number of elements (i.e. the length of the underlying vector). You should use `nrow` instead.

```
start_extend <- .indexyear(data)[nrow(data)] + 1900 + 1
end_extend <- start_extend + nrow(data) - 1
```

If you're not sure whether `data` will be a matrix or a vector, then you should use `NROW` instead of `nrow`. Calling `nrow` on a vector returns `NULL` and `NROW` will return `length(x)` if `x` is a vector.

Comment: Thank you @Joshua, I had spotted this error myself just now as I was combing through the function. I also noted that some further changes are necessary in order to run the code properly (I've added it to the question). 

This now seems to have the code run as intended. However there is still a minor snag. It seems that the if statement is now CONSTANTLY running... I change edhec to be odd and even, and the if statement is always applied. This suggests there is still something fundamentally wrong within the if statement.

Comment: @Visser: regarding your update, I think you need `if(!is.even(nyears_t))`.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the full answer that has the desired effect now. Thank you @Joshua for the help - I don't think I could have fixed the code without it. In order to run it on big data I had to make some additional changes.

For the sake of interest, this is my full working code (minus my additional custom functions):

```
bootOffset <- function(data, window, slide, tz = "GMT"){

    nyears_t = nyears(data)

  #IF statement for non-even numbers only
  if(is.even(nyears_t) == FALSE) {
    nyears_t <- roundUp(nyears_t)
    data_extend <- data

    start_extend <- .indexyear(data)[nrow(data)] + 1900 + 1
    end_extend <- start_extend + nyears(data) - 1

    dates <- index(data)
      tmp <- as.POSIXlt(dates); tmp$year <- tmp$year + nyears(data)
    dates2 <- as.POSIXct(tmp, tz = tz)

    index(data_extend) <- dates2
    data <- rbind(data, data_extend)
  }

    nslides = nyears_t/slide

    year_1 = (.indexyear(data)[1] + 1900)  

  #Matrix
  start <- seq(from = year_1, by = slide, length.out = nslides); end <- start + window - 1 
  mat <- matrix(c(start, end), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(c(1:nslides), c("start", "end")))

  #For loop
  subsetlist <- vector('list')

  for(i in 1:nslides){
    subset <- window(data, 
                     start = as.POSIXct(paste0(mat[i,1], "-01-01")), 
                     end = as.POSIXct(paste0(mat[i,2], "-12-31")))

    subsetlist[[i]] <- subset
  }
  print(subsetlist)
}
```

And for confirmation that these results come out as desired:

```
data(edhec, package = "PerformanceAnalytics")
edhec <- edhec[,1:3]
edhec08 <- edhec["/2008"]
edhec07 <- edhec["/2007"]

bootOffset(data = edhec08, #EVEN
                     window = 4,
                     slide = 3)

bootOffset(data = edhec07, #ODD
                     window = 4,
                     slide = 3)
```

#

```
> bootOffset.Check <- function(boot){
+ dates <- lapply(boot, year)
+ dates <- lapply(dates, unique)
+ dates <- lapply(dates, `length<-`, max(lengths(dates)))
+ as.data.frame(dates, 
+ col.names = paste0("boot_", 1:length(boot)))
+ 
+ }
> 
> nyears(edhec08)
[1] 12
> bootOffset.Check(boot08) #EVEN number of years
  boot_1 boot_2 boot_3 boot_4
1   1997   2000   2003   2006
2   1998   2001   2004   2007
3   1999   2002   2005   2008
4   2000   2003   2006     NA
> 
> nyears(edhec07)
[1] 11
> bootOffset.Check(boot07) #ODD number of years
  boot_1 boot_2 boot_3 boot_4
1   1997   2000   2003   2006
2   1998   2001   2004   2007
3   1999   2002   2005   2008
4   2000   2003   2006   2009
>
```